# How can I know if a specific button is the same as the "sender" to an event? C#

Tags: c#, events, button

I have a project in which I have implemented 70 buttons and declared each of them using an array `x`. When I click a button I need it to change color and other things which I have no problem with, so I have created an event, `ClickedButton`, that helps me do so. The code looks like this so far:

```
private void ClickedButton(object sender, EventArgs e)        
{
    Button button_send = (Button)sender;

    for (int i = 0; i < 70; i++)
        if (x[i] == button_send)
        /* 
            instructions
        */
}
```

The thing is, I need to know which button triggered the event by being clicked, because I need the `i` position. How do I do so? Obviously comparing them with  `==` doesn't work.

Comment: Please show how you declare and populate your `x` collection

Comment: Why would == not work?

Comment: use CommandArgument property to define some unique value for each button; retrieve that here to compare and write your logic

Comment: Is this winforms?  wpf?

Comment: Show your `x`-array, is it really a `Button[]`?

Comment: @TimSchmelter public Button[] x = new Button[100];

Comment: You could name you button and just compare the name.

Comment: _Obviously comparing them with == doesn't work._ __Why???__

Comment: @AdrianaUifaleanu: and you have also filled the array with the buttons? What doesn't work at all? Do you get an error?

Comment: @MathuSumMut I dont know! For example, if I write `x[i].BackColor = Color.Green;` after that `if`, nothing changes. :/

Comment: I'm sorry, I said "obviously" since I tried it and it didn't work. :/

Comment: @AdrianaUifaleanu: so the if isn't entered? Then you have to show how you fill the `Button[]`, currently it contains 100 null references. Of course those are `!= button_send `.

Comment: @Paparazzi wouldn't that have me comparing 70 button names?

Comment: Is it WinForms? WebForms?

Comment: `x[0] = button2; x[1] = button3; x[2] = button6; x[3] = button7; x[4] = button8; x[5] = button9;
            x[6] = button10; x[7] = button11; x[8] = button12; x[9] = button13; x[10] = button14; x[11] = button15;
            x[12] = button16; x[13] = button17; x[14] = button18; x[15] = button19; x[16] = button20; x[17] = button21;
            x[18] = button22;` and so on until the very last. The numbers dont match since I accidentally used button4 and button5 for something else.

Comment: Wow compare 70 button names.  You name need to get a faster processor.

Comment: @MaKCbIMKo it's windows forms!

Comment: @Paparazzi I'm sorry, I don't understand.

Comment: Then simple array.IndexOf() should work. Or, at the end, you can compare by btn.Id to find what you want.

Answer (score 1):

in wpf every button has a tag propery so you can set the tage property to the button positioin in the array.You can do something like

```
 int i=0;
 foreach(var button in x){
 button.tag=i;
 ++i;
}
```

then you can check for the tag like

```
private void ClickedButton(object sender, EventArgs e)        
{

        Button button_send = (Button)sender;
         int position=Convert.ToInt32(button_send.Tag)
        for (int i = 0; i < 70; i++)
            if (position==i)
            /* 
                instructions
            */
}
```

Comment: When i assign `i` to the `button.Tag` it gives me the error of `Object reference not set to the instance of an object.` :( What should I do?

Comment: is Your button array initialised? if it is not, initialised it  in the constractor and also put the first code block inside the constructor.hope it will help you

Comment: What is this supposed to do?  for (int i = 0; i < 70; i++) if (position==1)

Comment: sorry it is soppose to be (int i = 0; i < 70; i++) if (position==i) and not 1

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of platform - WinForms or WPF - controls have a `Tag` property:

```
public object Tag { get; set; }
```

What I have done in the past is assign a specific value to control `Tag`s. In this case, assign the `int`. You can then do something like the following:

```
private void ClickedButton(object sender, EventArgs e)        
{
    Button button_send = (Button)sender;
    var value = string.Empty;

    if (button_send.Tag != null && int.TryParse(button_send.Tag.ToString(), out value)
    {
        // check int 'value' against whatever logic you need
    }
}
```

Another option could be a dictionary:

```
Dictionary<Button, int>
```

The check gets much shorter and quicker in the event handler with a direct mapping to a specific value.

For what its worth, the `Tag` property is more flexible in the end. If it isn't an `int` your after, but maybe a delegate, you could just as easily store a reference to a `Func<T>` or `Action<T>` in the `Tag`.

Comment: how do i assign the `int` to the `Tag`?

Answer (score 0):

This statement `x[i] == button_send` should work just fine but the best way would be to attach a `id` with each button instance and comparing with that id like

Instead have a `List<Button>` can create button instance and add them like

```
Button b1 = new Button();
b1.id = "btn1";
x.Add(b1);
```

Then you can do like

```
x.Select(b => b.id == button_send.id);
```